# Amazon EC2 Code Deploy No hosts succeeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am new with Amazon Code Deploy. I am getting an error when deploying

> Deployment Failed
>   No hosts succeeded

I checked the service code deploy-agent on my Linux machine and it's running
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: btw if it help's when i am looking in the error page i can see also
Minimum Healthy Hosts 0 of 1 instances
any ideas?

Comment: We probably need more information to help you. Which command did you run ? What was the exact output ?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time this issue occur due to insufficient IAM Permission on the Instance and CodeDeploy Service. You need to check /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log file for detail information. Also in `/etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml` file you can set `:verbose: true` to get more info in log file.

These are the IAM Policies you need to update :

```
// Policy Role for Code Deploy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
 {
  "Action": [
    "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
    "autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook",
    "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat",
    "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
    "autoscaling:DescribeAutoscalingGroups",
    "autoscaling:PutInstanceInStandby",
    "autoscaling:PutInstanceInService",
    "ec2:Describe*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "*"
}
 ]
}

// Policy Trust for Code Deploy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": [
      "codedeploy.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
      "codedeploy.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    ]
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
 ]
}

// Instance Role for EC2 Instance
{ 
"Version": "2012-10-17", 
"Statement": [   
  {     
      "Action": [       
          "s3:Get*",       
          "s3:List*"     
      ],     
      "Effect": "Allow",     
      "Resource": "*"   
  } 
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As  BrunoLevy said, we will need more information about the the deployments you were trying to do.

However as a starting point for debugging, you can observe in which step your deployment failed from the deployment page

You can also look at the host agent log file on your hosts (/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log). That file contains information about the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the codeDeploy checks health of the ec2 instances by hitting instances. Before deployment, you need to run below bash script on the instances and check if the script worked. httpd service must be started. Reboot the instance.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo su
    yum update -y
    yum install httpd -y
    yum install ruby
    yum install aws-cli
    cd ~
    aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region us-east-1
    chmod +x ./install auto
    ./install auto
    echo 'hello world' > /var/www/html/index.html
    hostname >> /var/www/html/index.html
    chkconfig httpd on
    service httpd start
```